# A better way to work with circular foreign key references for new objects in EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, circular-reference

I work with EF 5.0, DB first in a web project.

For our service layer, we use Agatha with AutoMapper, so all data arrives in the service layer as POCO objects.

I have a data structure that look like this:

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? SelectedSecondClassId { get; set; }
    public SecondClass SelectedSecondClass { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SecondClass> MySecondClasses { get; set; } 

    //other properties go here
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentSecondClassId { get; set }
    public SecondClass ParentSecondClass { get; set; }

    //other properties go here
}
```

Now imagine I try to update a FirstClass object and do the following in 1 go:

- Create 2 new Secondclass objects in the MySecondClasses collection (both with id 0)
- Set one of these newly created objects as the SelectedSecondClass

Then EF refuses to play ball. I can't get it to work. If I look in the changetracker, I see that the SelectedSecondClass on the entity is empty again, but the SelectedSecondClassId is set to 0.  And that's something he can't resolve, because there are 2 objects with Id 0, before they are properly created.

If I do this, I can get stuff fixed:

```
var newId = -1;
foreach (var newSecondClass in firstClass.MySecondClasses.Where(x => x.Id <= 0))
{
    newSecondClass.Id = newId;
    newId --;
}

if (firstClass.SelectedSecondClass != null) 
{ 
    firstClass.SelectedSecondClassId = firstClass.SelectedSecondClass.Id;
}

// Send the updates to EF
```

As you understand, I feel like this is a bit hacked together and it would be easy for another developer to forget something like this. I would like to have a better way of doing this. Preferably in a way that I can 'fix' situations like this just before a SaveChanges() in my DbContext wrapper.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?